# add new item in appendchild xml c#

Tags: c#, xml, dom

i need to add a new item. this new item will be added as child. but it appears that it combined all the data input in only one child item. below is my code.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDoc.Load("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Documents\\SliceEngine\\SliceEngine\\bin\\Debug\\saya.xml");
XmlElement contentElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Name");
XmlElement itemEl = xmlDoc.CreateElement("item");
XmlText xmlText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(textBox1.Text.Trim());
itemEl.AppendChild(xmlText);
contentElement.AppendChild(itemEl);
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(contentElement);                

XmlElement thumbEl = xmlDoc.CreateElement("thumb");
XmlText xmlThumb = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(textBox2.Text.Trim());
itemEl.AppendChild(xmlThumb);
contentElement.AppendChild(thumbEl);
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(contentElement);
                    xmlDoc.Save("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Documents\\SliceEngine\\SliceEngine\\bin\\Debug\\saya.xml");
```

The output appears

```
<Name>
 <item>werasd</item>
 <thumb/> </Name>
```

but the output should appears

```
<Name>
     <item>wer</item>
     <thumb>asd<thumb/>
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`XmlElement.InnerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innertext.aspx). It gets or sets the concatenated values of the node. So that your code should be like this:

<s>`XmlText xmlThumb = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(textBox2.Text.Trim());
itemEl.AppendChild(xmlThumb);`</s>

```
// new code
thumbEl.InnerText = textBox2.Text.Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

you are appending it to wrong item change this

```
itemEl.AppendChild(xmlThumb);
```

to this

```
thumbEl.AppendChild(xmlThumb);
```